# I have enough gas fees still says Error : insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: solidity, web3js, hardhat

I am getting the following error

```
Deploying contracts with the account: 0xC5EE6A5a3F78c05636cb3678500287A2c8AcAb12
Account balance: 523927171098673317
Error: insufficient funds for intrinsic transaction cost [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS ] (error={"name":"ProviderError","_stack":"ProviderError: insufficient funds for gas * price + value\n    at HttpProvider.request
```

I am attempting to run the following script via hardhat

```
async function main() {
  const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

  console.log("Deploying contracts with the account:", deployer.address);

  console.log("Account balance:", (await deployer.getBalance()).toString());

  const Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("HyperleagueToken");
  const token = await Token.deploy();

  console.log("Token address:", token.address);

  const Nft = await ether.getContractFactory("Hyperleague");
  const nft = await Nft.deploy();

  console.log("Nft address:", nft.address);

  const MarketPlace = await ethers.getContractFactory("MarketPlace");
  const marketPlace = await MarketPlace.deploy(token.address, nft.address);
  
  console.log("MarketPlace address:", marketPlace.address);
  
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Here is `hardhat.config` file

```
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox");

const { mnemonic } = require('./secrets.json');

// This is a sample Hardhat task. To learn how to create your own go to
// https://hardhat.org/guides/create-task.html
task("accounts", "Prints the list of accounts", async () => {
  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners();

  for (const account of accounts) {
    console.log(account.address);
  }
});

// You need to export an object to set up your config
// Go to https://hardhat.org/config/ to learn more

/**
 * @type import('hardhat/config').HardhatUserConfig
 */
module.exports = {
  defaultNetwork: "mainnet",
  networks: {
    localhost: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
    },
    hardhat: {
    },
    testnet: {
      url: "https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545",
      chainId: 97,
      gasPrice: 50000000000,
      accounts: {mnemonic: mnemonic}
    },
    mainnet: {
      url: "https://bsc-dataseed.binance.org/",
      chainId: 56,
      accounts: {mnemonic: mnemonic}
    }
  },
  solidity: {
  version: "0.8.9",
  settings: {
    optimizer: {
      enabled: true
    }
   }
  },
  paths: {
    sources: "./contracts",
    tests: "./test",
    cache: "./cache",
    artifacts: "./artifacts"
  },
  mocha: {
    timeout: 20000
  }
};
```

Comment: The account you are using does not have enough BNB to cover the gas fees for the transactions

Comment: Account Balance is 0.5 BNB

Answer (score 1):

If you have 0.5 BNB be sure to check those things, the account you are using for the contract might not be the same, check again if it is the one in your `secrets.json` file, also your BNB balance could be on a different network check that it use the correct one in `hardhat.config.js` , be sure that you have exactly 0.5 BNB and not in another format like wei you can use this `console.log("Account balance:", ethers.utils.formatUnits(await deployer.getBalance(), 18));`